# Can We define Fourier transform (In Natural Sense) on function in $L^p$ for any p using denseness property of Schwartz Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I was reading Plancheral isometry theorem.

It uses denseness property of Schwartz space S to induce Fourier to transform on $L^2$

Also, S is dense in $L^p$ for all p

So can we used the same argument to induce Fourier to transform any function in $L^p$

I thought it is not possible due to fact for $L^2 $ we have weak Parseval relation which is not available for any other p

Is my argument is correct?

I have already read Tempered distribution I know we can define Fourier transform there which contain Lp but this in distribution sense Which is not natural definition of function I wanted to extend with original function definition

Any Help Hint in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: The largest space where you can reasonably define the Fourier transform is the space of tempered distributions; that is, the dual space of the Schwartz space. This is a pretty large space and it includes a copy of $L^p$ for any $p$. So yes, you can define the Fourier transform on $L^p$ for any $p$. If you search “Fourier transform of a tempered distribution” you will find many resources to read more about this.

Comment: @User8128 Dear Sir, I have read that . But that is sense on distribution. I wanted to know this in natural sense. Not in sense of distribution

Comment: @MathLover. What is "natural sense" for you?

Comment: Using the definition of Fourier transform on function (Not on distribution)

Comment: The Hausdorff Young inequality (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff%E2%80%93Young_inequality) could be interesting to you.

Comment: You are making a false dichotomy. Note this part of User8128's comment: "*it includes a copy of $L^p$ for any $p$*", i.e., $L^p$ can be identified with a subset of those distributions. That identification defines the Fourier transform on $L^p$. The elements of $L^p$ themselves are functions, not distributions, so this is defining the transform on functions, not distributions. By examining that Identification, you can express the "distributional" definition directly in terms of functions.